# Selecting Multiple Substrings from a Field

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, substring, case

I'm trying to create a SQL query that selects pieces of a record from a field.  Here is a shorten example of what is in one unedited field:

```
<Name>Example1</Name>
<Type>String</Type>
<Nullable>False</Nullable>
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY)</Prompt> 
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>    </Parameter>    
<Parameter> 
<Name>Example2</Name>      
<Type>String</Type>      
<Nullable>False</Nullable>      
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)</Prompt>      
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>      
<DefaultValues>        
<Value>%al%</Value>      
</DefaultValues>      
<Values>        
<Value>%al%</Value>      
</Values>    </Parameter>    
<Parameter>
```

A utter messy right, well I'm trying pull out all names, prompts and if it has a value then its value and put all of that into one field formated. For example the above field should look like this

```
Name: Example1
Prompt: Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY)
Name: Example2
Prompt: Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)
Value: %al%
```

I've tried using STUFF but there can be any number Names with Prompts and values in a single field.  My next thought was to use replace to replace all the <> and  but that would leave me with the stuff inbetween like so

```
Name: Example1
String
False
False
Prompt: Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY)
Name: Example2     
String      
False     
False
Prompt: Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)    
True  
Value: %al% 
%al%
```

Edit: Another idea that might solve the problem is if I can use REPLACE to replace the unknown length string between or along with the two known characters/strings for example replacing `<Type>###</Type>` where ### represents any number of characters inbetween the two known strings  and .  The problem is that I don't know if this is even possible or how to do it if it is.

Any suggestions are apperciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, SQL server 2008 r2

Comment: Show Your CODE that you have tried.

Comment: I'm trying to upload some code but it won't let me instead it is giving a error when I try and save the edit

Comment: The code that I'm trying now is a huge nested REPLACE statment similar to this only with many more replaces                   "REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8000), cc.[Parameter]), 
 '<Name>', 'Parameter: '),'<Prompt>', 'Prompt: ')"         It gives a output similar to the one found above in the last example output found above. I still can't save the code on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I checked the code with management studio and discover a few errors.

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
declare @tag nvarchar(max)
declare @label nvarchar(max)
declare @start int
declare @stop int
declare @len int
declare @needed int

set @var = '<Name>Example1</Name>
<Type>String</Type>
<Nullable>False</Nullable>
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY)</Prompt> 
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>        
<Parameter> </Parameter>
<Name>Example2</Name>      
<Type>String</Type>      
<Nullable>False</Nullable>      
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)</Prompt>      
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>      
<DefaultValues>        
<Value>%al%</Value>      
</DefaultValues>      
<Values>        
    <Value>%al%</Value>      
</Values>        
<Parameter></Parameter>'

set @needed = 0
set @start = charindex('<',@var)
set @stop = charindex('>',@var)
set @len = @stop - @start +1
set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@len)
set @label = substring(@var,@start+1,@len-2)
set @var =  replace(@var,@tag,@label + ' : ')

while(@start <> 0)
begin
    set @start = charindex('<',@var)
    set @stop = charindex('>',@var)
    set @len = @stop - @start +1
    if(@start <> 0)
    begin   
        set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@len)      
        if(charindex('/',@tag) = 0)
            begin
                set @label = substring(@var,@start+1,@len-2)+ ' : '     
                if(lower(@label) <> 'name : ' and lower(@label) <> 'value : ' and lower(@label) <> 'prompt : ')
                begin
                    set @needed = 0
                    set @var = replace(@var,@tag,'')
                    set @start = @stop - len(@tag)              
                    set @stop = charindex('<',@var)
                    set @len = @stop - @start
                    set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@len)                                      
                    set @var = replace(@var,@tag,'')
                end             
            end
        else
            begin
                set @label = ''
            end
        set @var = replace(@var,@tag,@label)
    end
end
print replace(@var,'
','')
```

and this results in:
    Name : Example1
    Prompt : Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY)
    Name : Example2
    Prompt : Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)            Value :
    %al%

Comment: Using slightly modified version of this code the problem was solved.  It's been a year since I did anything SQL related so being thrown into this problem was like being thrown into a tank of sharks. Thanks a lot for helping with the problem, I would not have solved it nearly as fast without you help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. If the problem is resolved, please mark the answer or submit your final code as the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I came up with. I hope it helps. basically it looks for the tags, if it's a closing tag it removes it and if it's an open tag it is replaces by the label variant.

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
declare @tag nvarchar(max)
declare @label nvarchar(max)
declare @start int
declare @stop int
declare @len int

set @var = '<Name>Example1</Name>
<Type>String</Type>
<Nullable>False</Nullable>
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY)</Prompt> 
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>        
<Parameter> </Parameter>
<Name>Example2</Name>      
<Type>String</Type>      
<Nullable>False</Nullable>      
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)</Prompt>      
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>      
<DefaultValues>        
<Value>%al%</Value>      
</DefaultValues>      
<Values>        
    <Value>%al%</Value>      
</Values>        
<Parameter></Parameter>'

set @start = charindex('<',@var)
set @stop = charindex('>',@var)
set @len = @stop - @start +1
set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@len)
set @label = substring(@var,@start+1,@len-2)
set @var =  replace(@var,@tag,@label + ' : ')

while(@start <> 0)
begin
set @start = charindex('<',@var)
set @stop = charindex('>',@var)
set @len = @stop - @start +1
    if(@start <> 0)
    begin
        set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@len)      
        if(charindex('/',@tag) = 0)
        begin
            set @label = substring(@var,@start+1,@len-2)+ ' : '
        end
        else
        begin
            set @label = ''
        end
        set @var = replace(@var,@tag,@label)
    end
end

print @var
```

this results in:
Name : Example1
Type : String
Nullable : False
AllowBlank : False
Prompt : Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY) 
PromptUser : True
Parameter :
Name : Example2
Type : String
Nullable : False
AllowBlank : False
Prompt : Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)
PromptUser : True
DefaultValues :
Value : %al%

Values :
Value : %al%

Parameter :

Comment: Thanks for the code, your output is similar to what I'm looking for though I'm looking for only the Name, Prompt, and values from the field.  Also there are multiple records with these values in that column that I need to pluck out, so I'm not 100% sure on how to set @var for that, but I'll continue to try.  Thanks for the help so far and if you or anyone else can think of a method or something to help please post it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code so that only the name, prompt and value parts will be saved.

A little warning though I changed the code in notepad++ so it could have a bug.
the idea is that you put this code in a function and pass the @var part as a parameter.

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
declare @tag nvarchar(max)
declare @label nvarchar(max)
declare @start int
declare @stop int
declare @len int
declare @needed int

set @var = '<Name>Example1</Name>
<Type>String</Type>
<Nullable>False</Nullable>
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Start Date (DD-MMM-YYYY)</Prompt> 
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>        
<Parameter> </Parameter>
<Name>Example2</Name>      
<Type>String</Type>      
<Nullable>False</Nullable>      
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
<Prompt>Case (Enter Case Number, % for all, OR %AL% for Alberta)</Prompt>      
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>      
<DefaultValues>        
<Value>%al%</Value>      
</DefaultValues>      
<Values>        
    <Value>%al%</Value>      
</Values>        
<Parameter></Parameter>'

set @start = charindex('<',@var)
set @stop = charindex('>',@var)
set @len = @stop - @start +1
set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@len)
set @label = substring(@var,@start+1,@len-2)
set @var =  replace(@var,@tag,@label + ' : ')

while(@start <> 0)
begin
    set @start = charindex('<',@var)
    set @stop = charindex('>',@var)
    set @len = @stop - @start +1
    if(@start <> 0)
    begin
        set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@len)      
        if(charindex('/',@tag) = 0)
        begin
            set @label = substring(@var,@start+1,@len-2)+ ' : '
            if(lower(@label) = 'name' or lower(@label) = 'value' or         lower(@label) = 'prompt')
            begin
                set @needed = 1
            end
            else
            begin
                set @needed = 0
            end
        end
        else
        begin
            set @label = ''
        end

        if(@needed = 1)
        begin
            set @var = replace(@var,@tag,@label)
            end
                else
                begin
                    set @var = replace(@var,@tag,'')
                    set @start = @stop
                    set @stop = charindex('<',@var)
                    set @tag = substring(@var,@start,@stop)
                set @var = replace(@var,@tag,'')
            end
        end
    end

    print @var
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Tried it out but it is giving errors that the parameters being passed to the substring function is invalid length, after playing around with it I found that the  if statement    if(lower(label) = 'name' or lower(label) = 'value' or lower(label) = 'prompt') isn't working since it only set needed to 1 when it is name not for the others for some unkown reason, in addation to that the len is getting negative values which could be caused by the if statment.  I tried to apply a similar solution but again the if statment isn't working.  Thanks thus far.

Comment: After playing around some more I discovered that the if statment doesn't work at all, the only reason why the name: showed up on my version was because I did name outside of a loop